# Use variable for json answer in QML BlackBerry

Tags: qml, blackberry-10, blackberry-cascades

I have a project in QML, MomenticsID (BlackBerry10).
I need to use the variable for json answer.
I can not find some manual for this problem.
When I use `var result = data.item_01[0]` everything is OK and program results in correct value.
But when I use `var result = data.variable` I won't get an answer.

main.qml

```
import bb.cascades 1.4
import bb.data 1.0

Page {
    id: page

    property string variable: "item_01[0]"

    Container {

        Label {
            id: label
        }
    }

    attachedObjects: [

        DataSource {
            id: dataSource
            type: DataSourceType.Json
            source: "asset:///data.json"

            onDataLoaded: {
                var result = data.item_01[0] // it's OK, result is "a"
                //var result = data.variable // it's NOK, nothing result

                label.text = result.answer_01
            }
        }
    ]

    onCreationCompleted: {
        dataSource.load()
    }
}
```

data.json

```
{
  "item_01": [
    {
      "answer_01": "a"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Should it be `data[page.variable]`?

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work. I got this error: asset:///main.qml:25: TypeError: Result of expression 'data' [[object Object]] is not a function.

Comment: Ok, you have to provide [mre], otherwise it's hard to understand the issue.